# Tesseract Train .TIff Files

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, tiff

Am in the process of creating a Custom OCR application on the top of Tesseract, Am still doing R&D work and I got stuck with a problem of training a multi page tiff document to extract specific fields from it, how I can achieve it ? once it is trained the upcoming same document will be extracted automatically or we need manual intervention ?

Sorry still am in R&D level I didn't put my hands on in coding, I have googled a lot but didn't able to find a proper solution, please help me to resolve this Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

I use PIL to read the tiff into an `ImageSequence`, then process the pages individually because that can be done in parallel if needed.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import pytesseract

im = Image.open(filename)
pages = ImageSequence.Iterator(im)
# n_pages = im.n_frames
for page in in pages:
    im = im.convert('L')
    pytesseract.image_to_data( ... )
```

Comment: how to train the images to get particular field from it any idea ?

Comment: could you help me in this ?